# Buttin inside the picker in iphone

Tags: xcode

i want to develop an application where i want to make the picker in horizontal way.Or the set of adjust the array in such way.

As shown in the image below:-

[image]

I got this kind of view.It is working perfectly this is atuly what i want functionally.But how can i keep such image (orange pointer on selected number and rounded rectangual image under that orange pointer).
http://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/
Please guide me how can i do this.

Solution of the Above question is:-

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    CGFloat width = 200.0f;
    CGFloat x = (self.view.frame.size.width - width) / 2.0f;
    CGRect tmpFrame = CGRectMake(x, 150.0f, width, 40.0f);
    pickerView = [[V8HorizontalPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:tmpFrame];
    pickerView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    pickerView.selectedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pickerView.textColor   = [UIColor grayColor];
    pickerView.delegate    = self;
    pickerView.dataSource  = self;
    pickerView.elementFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    pickerView.selectionPoint = CGPointMake(60, 0);

    // add carat or other view to indicate selected element
    UIImageView *indicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator"]];
    pickerView.selectionIndicatorView = indicator;
//  pickerView.indicatorPosition = V8HorizontalPickerIndicatorTop; // specify indicator's location
    [indicator release];

    // add gradient images to left and right of view if desired
//  UIImageView *leftFade = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_fade"]];
//  pickerView.leftEdgeView = leftFade;
//  [leftFade release];
//
//  UIImageView *rightFade = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_fade"]];
//  pickerView.rightEdgeView = rightFade;
//  [rightFade release];

    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];

    self.nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    tmpFrame = CGRectMake(x, 225.0f, width, 50.0f);
    nextButton.frame = tmpFrame;
    [nextButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(nextButtonClicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Center Element 0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    nextButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:nextButton];

    self.reloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    tmpFrame = CGRectMake(x, 300, width, 50.0f);
    reloadButton.frame = tmpFrame;
    [reloadButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(reloadButtonClicked:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [reloadButton setTitle:@"Reload Data" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:reloadButton];

    tmpFrame = CGRectMake(x, 375, width, 50.0f);
    infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:tmpFrame];
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    infoLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];
```

this will work with me properly and give this type of picker:-[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot do this with the standard picker that the article in the link uses. You cannot easily change how the picker shows its selection. You need to write this component completely yourself.

Comment: i got the solution i am appending the solution under my question my editing the question.